# Calculate the quadratic irrational number given by a certain periodic cont. fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Calculate the quadratic irrational number $\alpha$ given by the periodic continued fraction $\alpha = \overline{ [1,2,1] } $.

To be honest I am not sure how to tackle this one. I know the algorithm to construct a continued fraction given $\alpha$, but I am unsure how to reverse this algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha
= 1+\cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{\alpha
}}}$

Comment: I feel embarassed,( I am still learning cont. fractions, so sorry for my ignorant question). Thanks for your quick reply!